# scala unmarshelling xml want to capture cdata fields

Tags: xml, scala, pattern-matching

I am unmarshelling XML documents with CDATA fields that contain embedded xml documents and i want to unmarshall all of it. Sadly, the scala xml parser to DOM is retrieving the <.![CDATA[ ]]> tag in the cdata field. How am i suposed to capture it? My attempts so far is to try and pattern match the elements in the following way:

```
 node match {
    case Elem(_, _, _, _, Text(text)) => {
      if(text.startsWith("<") && text.endsWith(">")) map put(CDATA, fromXml(text))
      else                                           map put(TEXT, text)
    }
    case Elem(_, _, _, _, PCData(text)) => println(text) /* CDATA! */
    case _ => map ++= seqLoop(node \ "_") /* Not element must call children recursively */
  }
```

As you can see i am attempting to pattern match elements with cdata abut it is all falling on Text and i can only detect it with that ugly if case.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fitrst of all, it's not a good idea to be doing this. `<foo>&lt;bar/&gt;</foo>` and `<foo><![CDATA[<bar/>]]></foo>` are equivalent. Those are just a bit different ways to escape special characters. You [shouldn't depend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Uses_of_CDATA_sections) on the source returning one or the other.

If you can control the schema, you should use additional attributes or elements to specify that the text data is in XML format.

That said, it seems you *can* hijack scala XML library to produce `PCData` elements for CData sections, when parsing XML strings or files:

```
import scala.xml.{TopScope, InputSource, SAXParser, Elem, PCData}
import scala.xml.parsing.FactoryAdapter
import scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader
import org.xml.sax.ext.{LexicalHandler, DefaultHandler2}

object XMLLoaderWithCData extends XMLLoader[Elem] {
  def lexicalHandler(adapter: FactoryAdapter): LexicalHandler = 
    new DefaultHandler2 {
      def captureCData(): Unit = {
        adapter.hStack push PCData(adapter.buffer.toString)
        adapter.buffer.clear()
      }

      override def startCDATA(): Unit = adapter.captureText()
      override def endCDATA(): Unit = captureCData()
    }

  override def loadXML(source: InputSource, parser: SAXParser): Elem = {
    val newAdapter = adapter

    val xmlReader = parser.getXMLReader
    xmlReader.setProperty(
      "http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", 
      lexicalHandler(newAdapter))

    newAdapter.scopeStack push TopScope
    parser.parse(source, newAdapter)
    newAdapter.scopeStack.pop()

    newAdapter.rootElem.asInstanceOf[Elem]
  }
}
```

You can use this `XMLLoaderWithCData` mostly as a normal `scala.xml.XML` object:

```
scala> val x = "<foo><bar>aaa<![CDATA[<111/>]]>bbb</bar><![CDATA[<bar/>]]></foo>"
x: String = <foo><bar>aaa<![CDATA[<111/>]]>bbb</bar><![CDATA[<bar/>]]></foo>

scala> XMLLoaderWithCData.loadString(x)
res0: scala.xml.Elem = <foo><bar>aaa<![CDATA[<111/>]]>bbb</bar><![CDATA[<bar/>]]></foo>
```

This implementation is of course quite brittle and depends on implementation details of Scala library, and thus may break in case of future updates.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I have been looking for a solution for two straight days and i knew i had to somehow override the scala.xml parser. I will test this for performance to see how it will degrade the current time.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = XML.loadString(xmlString)
var cdata=(a \\ "tagwithCdata").text
var b=  XML.loadString(cdata)
```

Now you can parse `b` as XML node.